# How to calculate the product of two series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let us consider the two series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\left(\frac{n^{2\alpha-1}-1}{n^\alpha}\right) \cos(\beta \ln n)$$ 
and 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\left(\frac{n^{2\alpha-1}-1}{n^\alpha}\right) \sin(\beta \ln n).$$ 
Both series converge for $0<\alpha<1$. My **question** is: How to calculate the product of these two series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally when we multiply two series we collect "like terms" but for these series it is not evident what the like terms are.  Hence the best I personally can do is
$$\sum_{m,n\ge 1} (-1)^{m+n}\frac{(n^{2\alpha-1}-1)(m^{2\alpha-1}-1)}{(mn)^\alpha}\cos(\beta \ln n)\sin(\beta \ln m)$$